# How to select only values based on another column condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, data-analysis

I have a table having this format

```
id    col1     avg_amount_per_order
1     a        80
1     b        50
2     a        90
2     b        120
3     a        200
3     b        140
4     a        110
4     b        430
```

I want to select all the data, as long as if `col1 = a`, then the `avg_amount_per_order` must `be >= 100`. And for the same id, I only want to select rows, where `avg_amount_per_order` of `'b'` is at least `2*` `avg_amount_per_order` of `'a'` in `col1`.

How to do that?

I tried this:

```
SELECT 
id
, col1
, avg_amount_per_order

from orders

WHERE
nr_orders >= 6
    AND CASE WHEN col1 = 'a' THEN avg_amount_per_order >= 100 ELSE avg_amount_per_order > 0 END

group by 
1,2,3
```

but this doesn't return the results like expected.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a simple way to reach a solution for your issue.

```
with tbl(id, col1, avg_amount_per_order) as (
values
(1, 'a', 80 ),
(1, 'b', 50 ),
(2, 'a', 90 ),
(2, 'b', 120),
(3, 'a', 200),
(3, 'b', 140),
(4, 'a', 110),
(4, 'b', 430)
)
select a.* 
from tbl a 
join tbl b on a.id = b.id and a.col1 != b.col1
WHERE (a.avg_amount_per_order  >= b.avg_amount_per_order * 2 
and  b.col1 = 'a' and b.avg_amount_per_order >= 100)
or  a.avg_amount_per_order *2 <= b.avg_amount_per_order
```

Comment: this returns only 'a' values where avg_amount >= 100. I did not found in resultset any 'b' value in col1. Although there are in source table. ie. there are meeting that conditions (avg_amount of b >= 2* avg_amount of a for same id).

Comment: I thought you just comparing by same id @ZelelB, I'll fix now

Comment: I want to select only rows which have avg_amount >= 100 for 'a' and only rows where  (avg_amount of 'b' >= 2* avg_amount of 'a' for same id)

Comment: @ZelelB I edited my answer, I hope I got you right.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [LEAD](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-window.html) window function to get values and `a` and `b` together. Then an outer query to the the `b>= 2*a`:

```
select id, avg_amount_per_order_a, avg_amount_per_order_b
  from ( select id
              , avg_amount_per_order avg_amount_per_order_a 
              , lead(avg_amount_per_order) over (partition by id order by  col1) avg_amount_per_order_b  
           from testa 
       ) ab
 where avg_amount_per_order_b >= 2 * avg_amount_per_order_a;
   and avg_amount_per_order_a > 100.;
```

Comment: And what about the condition of a minimum of 100 in the avg_amount_per_order for col1 IF it's value is 'a'? Where does this reflect here?

Comment: Simply add that condition as `where ...` or as `and ...` as appropriate to the location. Do both or only one work?  I have updated the answer  with one you should try the other. What is the difference?

Answer (score 0):

```
with data as (
    select *,
        min(avg_amount_per_order) filter (where col1 = 'a') over (partition by id) as avgA,
        min(avg_amount_per_order) filter (where col1 = 'b') over (partition by id) as avgB
    from T
)
select * from data
where avgA >= 100 and avgB >= 2 * avgA
-- ?? where col1 = 'a' and avgA >= 100 or col1 = 'b' and avgB >= 2 * avgA
```

I can't tell whether you want only one condition or both of them together.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=899bbf580ae7d3f1176f00632c012c2c

Comment: "filter" does not work in PostgreSQL. Getting a syntax error there on filter (col1 = 'a')

Comment: @ZelelB It's supposed to go before the `over`.

Answer (score 0):

This might be possible using `OR` and `EXISTS`.

> ```
> SELECT *
> FROM yourtable t
> WHERE (
>    (col1='a' AND avg_amount_per_order >= 100)
> OR (col1 IS DISTINCT FROM 'a'
>     AND EXISTS (
>         select 1 
>         from yourtable a
>         where a.col1='a' 
>           and a.avg_amount_per_order >= 100
>           and t.avg_amount_per_order >= 2 * a.avg_amount_per_order
> )));
> ```

| id | col1 | avg_amount_per_order |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | a | 200 |
| 4 | a | 110 |
| 4 | b | 430 |

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=d6512752735a03c6b69145bad77f750a)*

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would approach it:

1. Find ID's that satisfy requirements for col1='a'
2. Find ID's that satisfy requirements for col1='b'
3. Select * from original table where id is in the union of the above

Here is what I came up with:

```
with filter_on_a as (
    select distinct id from table 
    where col1 = 'a' and avg_amount_per_order >= 100
),filter_on_b_input as (
    select a.*, b.avg_amount_per_order as avg_amount_per_order_b
    from (select * from table where col1 = 'a') a 
    left join (select * from table where col1 = 'b') b
    on a.id = b.id
, filter_on_b as (
    select distinct id from table 
    where concat(cast(id as string),col1) in
        (select concat(cast(id as string),'b')
         from filter_on_b_input
         where avg_amount_per_order_b / avg_amount_per_order >= 2)
), select * from table 
where id in (select id from filter_on_a union select id from filter_on_b)
```